# REST servlet fusion with already existing Application ( Apache Tomcat 7, MySQL, Spring Servlets)

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat, servlets

I've seen number of tutorials, I read many articles about how to use REST in Apache Tomcat, but still I can't make it work. I'm misssing something crutial. 
So I have Web Server Application with build on DWR. Single web page of my application is based on DWR java file which allows to communication between javascript and server. I need to implement REST sub-page, which will be based on REST. 
I general my problem is that i have existing web.xml with

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
<!-- 
Context parameters.
 -->
<context-param>
<param-name>com.serotonin.web.taglib.ListSortTag.styleClass</param-name>
<param-value>rowHeaderLink</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>com.serotonin.web.taglib.ListSortTag.imageAlign</param-name>
<param-value>top</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>com.serotonin.web.taglib.ListSortTag.upImage.src</param-name>
<param-value>images/icon_arrow_up.png</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>com.serotonin.web.taglib.ListSortTag.upImage.width</param-name>
<param-value>16</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>com.serotonin.web.taglib.ListSortTag.upImage.height</param-name>
<param-value>16</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>com.serotonin.web.taglib.ListSortTag.upImage.altKey</param-name>
<param-value>pagination.ascending</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>com.serotonin.web.taglib.ListSortTag.downImage.src</param-name>
<param-value>images/icon_arrow_down.png</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>com.serotonin.web.taglib.ListSortTag.downImage.width</param-name>
<param-value>16</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>com.serotonin.web.taglib.ListSortTag.downImage.height</param-name>
<param-value>16</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>com.serotonin.web.taglib.ListSortTag.downImage.altKey</param-name>
<param-value>pagination.descending</param-value>
</context-param>


<!-- 
Filter definitions.
 -->
<filter>
<filter-name>CharacterSet</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.serotonin.web.filter.CharacterSetFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>charset</param-name>
<param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
<filter-name>IsLoggedIn</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.serotonin.mango.web.filter.NormalLoggedInFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>forwardUrl</param-name>
<param-value>/login.htm</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
<filter-name>WebContext</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.serotonin.mango.web.filter.WebContextFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
<filter-name>CacheHeaders</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.serotonin.mango.web.filter.HttpResponseHeaderFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>Cache-Control</param-name>
<param-value>max-age=5184000</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>


<!-- 
Filter mappings.
 -->
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CharacterSet</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CharacterSet</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.shtm</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>IsLoggedIn</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.shtm</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>WebContext</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.shtm</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CacheHeaders</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/dwr/interfaces/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CacheHeaders</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/dwr/engine.js</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CacheHeaders</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/dwr/utils.js</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CacheHeaders</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/audio/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CacheHeaders</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CacheHeaders</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/graphics/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CacheHeaders</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
 <filter-name>HttpResponseHeaderFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class> com.serotonin.mango.web.filter.HttpResponseHeaderFilter</filter-class>
 <init-param>
 <param-name>Cache-Control</param-name>
 <param-value>max-age=5184000</param-value>
 </init-param>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>HttpResponseHeaderFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
 
 <filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>HttpResponseHeaderFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>


<!-- 
Servlet definitions.
 -->
 <servlet>
    <display-name>CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jaxrs.serviceClasses</param-name>
      <param-value>service.DataPointRestService</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jaxrs.address</param-name>
      <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>debug</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>publishContainerAs</param-name>
<param-value>DwrContainer</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>crossDomainSessionSecurity</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>imageChart</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.serotonin.mango.web.servlet.ImageChartServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>asyncImageChart</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.serotonin.mango.web.servlet.AsyncImageChartServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>reportExport</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.serotonin.mango.web.servlet.ReportExportServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>reportEventExport</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.serotonin.mango.web.servlet.ReportEventExportServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>reportUserCommentExport</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.serotonin.mango.web.servlet.ReportUserCommentExportServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>reportChart</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.serotonin.mango.web.servlet.ReportChartServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>httpDataSource</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.serotonin.mango.web.servlet.HttpDataSourceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>imageValue</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.serotonin.mango.web.servlet.ImageValueServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>


<!-- 
Servlet mappings.
 -->
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.shtm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>imageChart</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/chart/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>asyncImageChart</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/achart/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>reportChart</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/reportImageChart/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>reportExport</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/export/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>reportEventExport</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/eventExport/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>reportUserCommentExport</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/userCommentExport/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>httpDataSource</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/httpds</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>imageValue</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/imageValue/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CacheHeaders</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CacheHeaders</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CacheHeaders</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/dwr/interfaces/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CacheHeaders</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/dwr/engine.js</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CacheHeaders</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/dwr/utils.js</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- 
Context listeners.
 -->
<listener><listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class></listener>
<listener><listener-class>com.serotonin.mango.MangoContextListener</listener-class></listener>

<!-- 
Other stuff.
 -->
<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<error-page>
<exception-type>com.serotonin.mango.vo.permission.PermissionException</exception-type>
<location>/exception/accessDenied.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
<error-code>500</error-code>
<location>/exception/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/exception/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>JavascriptServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>net.jawr.web.servlet.JawrServlet</servlet-class>

<!-- Location in classpath of the config file -->
<init-param>
<param-name>configLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/jawr.properties</param-value>
</init-param>
 <init-param>
 <param-name>mapping</param-name>
 <param-value>/jsBundle/</param-value>
 </init-param>
<load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>JavascriptServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/jsBundle/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I've created classes and service, which are build successfully in my Project (using JSON-RI, Apache CFX):

```
package  com.serotonin.service;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import com.serotonin.domain.DataPoint;
import com.serotonin.domain.DataPointLists;
import com.serotonin.domain.DataPointManager;

/**
 * The jax-rs service, deployable to Apache, which tracks data points.
 * 
 * @author
 *
 */
@Path("/datapoint")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })

public class DataPointRestService {
    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo;

    /**
     * Create a data point and add it to the data point manager.
     * 
     * @param dataPoint the data point to create
     * @return the status and url of the data point
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    @POST
    public Response create(DataPoint dataPoint) throws Exception {
        if (dataPoint == null)
            throw new Exception();
        DataPointManager.add(dataPoint);
        URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder()
                .path(dataPoint.getName())
                .build();
        return Response.created(uri)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Update a food with new information.
     * 
     * @param dataPoint the data point to update.
     * @return status code
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    @PUT
    public Response update(DataPoint dataPoint) throws Exception {
        if (dataPoint == null)
            throw new Exception();
        DataPointManager.delete(dataPoint.getName());
        DataPointManager.add(dataPoint);
        return Response.ok()
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Get a data point.
     * 
     * @param name the data point to get.
     * @return the status and data point.
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    @GET
    @Path("{name}")
    public Response get(@PathParam("name") String name) throws Exception {
        DataPoint dataPoint = DataPointManager.find(name);
        if (dataPoint == null)
            throw new Exception();
        return Response.ok(dataPoint)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Get all data points in the data point manager.
     * 
     * @return xml or json of all data points
     */
    @GET
    public Response getAll() {
        DataPointLists dataPointLists = DataPointManager.getListsOfPoints();
        GenericEntity<List<DataPoint>> list = new GenericEntity<List<DataPoint>>(dataPointLists) {
        };
        return Response.ok(list)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Delete a data point.
     * 
     * @param name data point to delete
     * @return status of the operation
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    @DELETE
    @Path("{name}")
    public Response delete(@PathParam("name") String name)  {
        DataPoint dataPoint = DataPointManager.find(name);
        if (dataPoint == null)
        DataPointManager.delete(name);
        return Response.noContent()
                .build();
    }

}
```

And then :

```
 package com.serotonin.domain;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 * Data holder for data points in list-of-data-points.shtm
 * @author beata 
 * Sample data point : 
 * masterPointer":false,"dataSourceId":7,"settable":false,"xid":"pd","typeKey":"event.audit.dataPoint","name":"pd","id":5573,"folderId":9999,"enabled":true
 */
@XmlRootElement
public class DataPoint {
    boolean masterPointer;
    int dataSourceId;
    boolean settable;
    String xid;
    String typeKey;
    String name;    
    int id;
    int folderId; 
    boolean enabled;



    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public DataPoint() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    /**
     * Constructor 
     * 
     * @param name
     * @param xid
     * @param id
     * @param enabled
     * @param settable
     * @param folderId
     * @param masterPointer
     * @param dataSourceId
     * @param typeKey
     */
    public DataPoint(String name, String xid, int id, boolean enabled, boolean settable, int folderId,
            boolean masterPointer, int dataSourceId, String typeKey) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.xid = xid;
        this.id = id;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.settable = settable;
        this.folderId = folderId;
        this.masterPointer = masterPointer;
        this.dataSourceId = dataSourceId;
        this.typeKey = typeKey;
    }


    public DataPoint(String string, boolean b, String string2, int i, String string3, boolean c, String string4,
            String string5, String string6, String string7, String string8, String string9, String string10, int j,
            String string11, int k, String string12, boolean d) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DataPoint [name=" + name + ", xid=" + xid + ", id=" + id + ", enabled=" + enabled + ", settable="
                + settable + ", folderId=" + folderId + ", masterPointer=" + masterPointer + ", dataSourceId="
                + dataSourceId + ", typeKey=" + typeKey + "]";
    }



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getXid() {
        return xid;
    }


    public void setXid(String xid) {
        this.xid = xid;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }


    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }


    public boolean isSettable() {
        return settable;
    }


    public void setSettable(boolean settable) {
        this.settable = settable;
    }


    public int getFolderId() {
        return folderId;
    }


    public void setFolderId(int folderId) {
        this.folderId = folderId;
    }


    public boolean isMasterPointer() {
        return masterPointer;
    }


    public void setMasterPointer(boolean masterPointer) {
        this.masterPointer = masterPointer;
    }


    public int getDataSourceId() {
        return dataSourceId;
    }


    public void setDataSourceId(int dataSourceId) {
        this.dataSourceId = dataSourceId;
    }


    public String getTypeKey() {
        return typeKey;
    }


    public void setTypeKey(String typeKey) {
        this.typeKey = typeKey;
    }


}
```

Next :

```
    package com.serotonin.domain;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

/**
 * 
 * @author beata
 *
 */
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso(DataPoint.class)
public class DataPointLists extends ArrayList<DataPoint> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public DataPointLists() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param c
     *            collection of initial data points .
     */
    public DataPointLists(Collection<? extends DataPoint> c) {
        super(c);
    }

    /**
     * Get list of points.
     * 
     * @return data points list
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "list-of-points")
    public List<DataPoint> getDataPointLists() {
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Add a list of data points.
     * 
     * @param dataPoints
     *            list to add
     */
    public void addFoods(List<DataPoint> dataPoints) {
        this.addAll(dataPoints);
    }

}


package com.serotonin.domain;

import java.util.Optional;

/**
 * Manages CRUD operations for data points.
 * 
 * @author 
 *
 */
public class DataPointManager {
    private static DataPointLists list = new DataPointLists();

    static { // initialize with some data

    // TODO: DATABASE REQUEST AND CONSTRUCTION OF POINT LISTS   
    //  

    // TEMPORARY TO HAVE SOMETHING TO READ  
    list.add(new DataPoint("masterPointer",false, "dataSourceId",7,"settable",false,"xid","pd","typeKey",
                                "event.audit.dataPoint","name","pd","id",5573,"folderId",9999,"enabled",true));

    list.add(new DataPoint("masterPointer",false,"dataSourceId",9,"settable",false,"xid","DP_007365","typeKey",
            "event.audit.dataPoint","name","A_OutForceN3","id",10526,"folderId",9999,"enabled",true));

    list.add(new DataPoint("masterPointer",false,"dataSourceId",9,"settable",false,"xid","DP_079182",
            "typeKey","event.audit.dataPoint","name","A_InEmulN3","id",10520,"folderId",9999,"enabled",true));

    list.add(new DataPoint("masterPointer",false,"dataSourceId",9,"settable",false,"xid","DP_112452","typeKey",
            "event.audit.dataPoint","name","ANALOGTEST13","id",10541,"folderId",9999,"enabled",true));

    }

    /**
     * Get all existing data points.
     * 
     * @return data point list
     */
    public static DataPointLists getListsOfPoints() {
        return list;
    }

    /**
     * Find a data point in the list of data points.
     * 
     * @param name
     *            data point to find
     * @return food or null
     */
    public static DataPoint find(String name) {
        final Optional<DataPoint> foundDataPoint = list.stream()
                .filter(dp -> dp.getName()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(name))
                .findFirst();
        return foundDataPoint.orElse(null);
    }

    /**
     * Add a data point to the list of data points.
     * 
     * @param dataPoint
     *            data point to add
     */
    public static void add(DataPoint dataPoint) {
        list.add(dataPoint);
    }

    /**
     * Delete a data point from the list of points.
     * 
     * @param name
     *            data point to delete
     */
    public static void delete(String name) {
        DataPoint dataPoint = find(name);
        list.remove(dataPoint);
    }

}
```

web.xml which needs to merged with this on the top of my post:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>DataPointRestServiceApache</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jaxrs.serviceClasses</param-name>
      <param-value>service.DataPointRestService</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jaxrs.address</param-name>
      <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

A have also files AppplicationContext.xml and SpringDispatcher in my application:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>
    <!-- DWR -->
    <bean id="DataPointDetailsDwr" class="com.serotonin.mango.web.dwr.DataPointDetailsDwr" />
    <bean id="DataPointEditDwr" class="com.serotonin.mango.web.dwr.DataPointEditDwr" />
    <bean id="SystemSettingsDwr" class="com.serotonin.mango.web.dwr.SystemSettingsDwr" />
    <bean id="UsersDwr" class="com.serotonin.mango.web.dwr.UsersDwr" />
    <bean id="ViewDwr" class="com.serotonin.mango.web.dwr.ViewDwr" />
    <bean id="WatchListDwr" class="com.serotonin.mango.web.dwr.WatchListDwr" />
</beans>
```

SpringDispatcher+servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<!-- - Application context definition for DispatcherServlet. -->
<beans>

    <!-- URL mappings to controllers -->
    <bean id="publicUrlMappings"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/sql.shtm">sqlController</prop>
                <prop key="/system_settings.shtm">systemSettingsController</prop>
                <prop key="/users.shtm">usersController</prop>
                <prop key="/watch_list.shtm">watchListController</prop>
                <prop key="/webcam_live_feed.htm">webcamLiveFeedController</prop>
                <prop key="/list-of-points.shtm">listOfPointsController</prop>

            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="commonData" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="loginController" class="com.serotonin.mango.web.mvc.controller.LoginController">
        <property name="commandName">
            <value>login</value>
        </property>
        <property name="commandClass">
            <value>com.serotonin.mango.web.mvc.form.LoginForm</value>
        </property>
        <property name="formView">
            <value>login</value>
        </property>
        <property name="successUrl">
            <value>watch_list.shtm</value>
        </property>
        <property name="newUserUrl">
            <value>help.shtm</value>
        </property>
        <property name="bindOnNewForm">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="logoutController" class="com.serotonin.mango.web.mvc.controller.LogoutController">
        <property name="redirectUrl">
            <value>login.htm</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlController" class="com.serotonin.mango.web.mvc.controller.SqlController">
        <property name="commandName">
            <value>form</value>
        </property>
        <property name="commandClass">
            <value>com.serotonin.mango.web.mvc.form.SqlForm</value>
        </property>
        <property name="formView">
            <value>sql</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="listOfPointsController"
        class="com.serotonin.mango.web.mvc.controller.ListOfPointsController">
        <property name="viewName">
            <value>listOfpoints</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

My question is how to merge web.xml ? Is my approach is correct and if it is right one? Maybe I can do this with different approach.